# Rest-assured request using Azure SAS token always returns 403

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops, rest-assured, azure-cli

I am using azure-cli to generate SAS token

```
az storage blob generate-sas --account-key mykey --account-name myaccount --container-name my --expiry 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z --name 0.0.1/uk/787867898767/structure/calendar/a12calendar.json --permissions r
```

Which returns a SAS token which looks like:

```
se=2023-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&sp=r&sv=2020-02-10&sr=b&sig=u2VWd2i8cdYhkjA%2BZRBCYZbHwmZDCrjirs%2BYstwxmjI%3D
```

I have a rest assured test which does a GET to

`given().get("https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/0.0.1/uk/787867898767/structure/calendar/a12calendar.json?se=2023-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&sp=r&sv=2020-02-10&sr=b&sig=u2VWd2i8cdYhkjA%2BZRBCYZbHwmZDCrjirs%2BYstwxmjI%3DD").then().statusCode(200)`

which fails with a HTTP 403.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:5ab15b27-701e-00b3-298c-b0ffa0000000
Time:2021-09-23T15:08:56.1619254Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

**BUT the same url works fine on Postman and Chrome**. Looks like some kind of encoding issue, but can't find what. Any help would be hugely appreciated .

Comment: I am guessing that something is going on with encoding of your SAS token. Can you try by decoding the sas token and using that in your test. Your SAS token after decoding should look something like `se=2023-01-01T00:00:00Z&sp=r&sv=2020-02-10&sr=b&sig=u2VWd2i8cdYhkjA+ZRBCYZbHwmZDCrjirs+YstwxmjI=`.

Comment: @GauravMantri - yes you are right.  I have shared the answer below. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue was with default RestAssured settings.

RestAssured has `urlEncodingEnabled = true` by default.

Set it to false using

```
RestAssured.urlEncodingEnabled = false;
```

if you face issue with url encoding.